# how do i make a search function for a list generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So basically, I'm displaying data from a json url into a list.
This is my script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $.ajax({
    "url":"http://something.com/myfile.json",
    "crossDomain":true,
    "dataType":"jsonp",      
    'success': function(response){ 

    var collection = response.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){   

        $(".list-item").append( '<li><a href="' + results.url +'" class="invites"><span>' + results.title + '</span></a></li>');

  }},
      error: function(err){
          alert('error!' + err);
      } 
});
});
```

and i display it in a list. This is the html

```
<div class="box_list">
    <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-item" ></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Everything is working fine but I'd like to add a search box at the top so anyone can search the list with keywords and I can't find how to do it. For example, I tried with dynatable but i couldn't make it work. Help?

(and if you can tell me how to implement pagination on my list that would be the cherry on the cake)
Thanks in advance!

Update!
I finally made it work! Guess I just needed to sleep... I used [this tutorial](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/May/12/Filtering-List-Data-with-a-jQuerysearchFilter-Plugin), hopefully it can help other novices like me. Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: Could you post what you tried for searching? It's a lot easier to help the more specific you are!

Comment: There are numerous Javascript libraries out there designed for just this sort of thing. My favorite is [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs). As for wiring it up, it's as simple as attaching an event handler to your search button. But, you could also look into Javascript framworks such as [angularjs](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro) or [knockoutjs](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro).

Comment: This a nice Javascript library that can help you: [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. I feel I'm too new at this and I'm missing something super simple because I tried so many plugins and none worked. I'll look at the links you gave after some sleep because I'm too tired right now to try anything. Hopefully I'll wake up less dumb tomorrow et make something work. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you might be interested in https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/